# Angular directives collision

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, collision

I would like to use 2 directives in the same app. The problem is that when I use the second one, the first one crashes with an ugly error: `TypeError: Failed to execute 'getComputedStyle' on 'Window': parameter 1 is not of type 'Element'`.

The first directive is angular-fullpage.js (https://github.com/hellsan631/angular-fullpage.js) and the second one is angular bootstrap affix implementation (https://github.com/maxisam/angular-bootstrap-affix).

When I include both modules (directives), the fullpage directive crashes with the afformentioned error. If I remove the affix directive, then fullpage.js Works fine (just by removing the second directive from the modules).

How can I avoid directive collision? Are there any workarounds for this issue or should I just settle for just 1 of the directives?

Thanks!!!!

app.js:

```
var myApp = angular
    .module(
    'myApp',
    [
        'ngRoute',
        'ngAnimate',
        'ngMessages',
        'ui.bootstrap',
        'angular-loading-bar',
        'LocalStorageModule',
        'ngEnter',
        'ng-Static-Include',
        'ngResource',
        'toastr',
        'ng-Static-Include',
        'pageslide-directive',
        'ngRutChange',
        'xmsbsStopPropagation',
        'ngEnter',
        'ng-rut',
        'ngMessages',
        'duScroll',
        'dynamicNumber',
        'xmsbsDirectives',
        'salfaDirectives',
        'mgcrea.bootstrap.affix',
        'fullPage.js',
        'ui.tinymce',
        'mega-menu',
        'bootstrap.fileField',
        'ngTagsInput'
    ]);
```

Partial view (home) trying to use the fullpage directive and generating the error:

```
<div class="section">
    <div ng-style="{'width': '100%', 'height': vm.divHeight+'px'}" style="margin-top:-7px;background:url(/content/images/03.jpg) center center; background-size:cover;">
        <div class="col-sm-12">
            <h1 class="fg-grayLight text-center text-shadow vert-align-center" style="z-index:2;" ng-style="{'padding-top':vm.divHeight/9+'px'}">sistema de recursos humanos 2.0</h1>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="section">
    <div class="col-sm-12">
        <h2 class="text-center">noticias</h2>
    </div>
</div>
```

Affix directive:

```
'use strict';

angular.module('mgcrea.bootstrap.affix', ['mgcrea.jquery'])

  .directive('bsAffix', function($window, dimensions) {

    var checkPosition = function(instance, el, options) {

      var scrollTop = window.pageYOffset;
      var scrollHeight = document.body.scrollHeight;
      var position = dimensions.offset.call(el[0]);
      var height = dimensions.height.call(el[0]);
      var offsetTop = options.offsetTop * 1;
      var offsetBottom = options.offsetBottom * 1;
      var reset = 'affix affix-top affix-bottom';
      var affix;

      if(instance.unpin !== null && (scrollTop + instance.unpin <= position.top)) {
        affix = false;
      } else if(offsetBottom && (position.top + height >= scrollHeight - offsetBottom)) {
        affix = 'bottom';
      } else if(offsetTop && scrollTop <= offsetTop) {
        affix = 'top';
      } else {
        affix = false;
      }

      if (instance.affixed === affix) return;

      instance.affixed = affix;
      instance.unpin = affix === 'bottom' ? position.top - scrollTop : null;

      el.removeClass(reset).addClass('affix' + (affix ? '-' + affix : ''));
    };

    var checkCallbacks = function(scope, instance, iElement, iAttrs) {
      if(instance.affixed) {
        if(iAttrs.onUnaffix)
          eval("scope." + iAttrs.onUnaffix);
      }
      else {
        if(iAttrs.onAffix)
          eval("scope." + iAttrs.onAffix);
      }
    };

    return {
      restrict: 'EAC',
      link: function postLink(scope, iElement, iAttrs) {
        var instance = {unpin: null};

        angular.element($window).bind('scroll', function() {
          checkPosition(instance, iElement, iAttrs);
          checkCallbacks(scope, instance, iElement, iAttrs);
        });

        angular.element($window).bind('click', function() {
          setTimeout(function() {
            checkPosition(instance, iElement, iAttrs);
            checkCallbacks(scope, instance, iElement, iAttrs);
          }, 1);
        });
      }
    };

  });
```

fullpage directive (this directive requires the original jQuery fullpage lugin to work http://www.alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/):

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    angular
      .module('fullPage.js', [])
      .directive('fullPage', fullPage);

    fullPage.$inject = ['$timeout'];

    function fullPage($timeout) {
        var directive = {
            restrict: 'A',
            scope: { options: '=' },
            link: link
        };

        return directive;

        function link(scope, element) {
            var pageIndex;
            var slideIndex;
            var afterRender;
            var onLeave;
            var onSlideLeave;

            if (typeof scope.options === 'object') {
                if (scope.options.afterRender) {
                    afterRender = scope.options.afterRender;
                }

                if (scope.options.onLeave) {
                    onLeave = scope.options.onLeave;
                }

                if (scope.options.onSlideLeave) {
                    onSlideLeave = scope.options.onSlideLeave;
                }
            } else if (typeof options === 'undefined') {
                scope.options = {};
            }

            var rebuild = function () {
                destroyFullPage();

                $(element).fullpage(sanatizeOptions(scope.options));

                if (typeof afterRender === 'function') {
                    afterRender();
                }
            };

            var destroyFullPage = function () {
                if ($.fn.fullpage.destroy) {
                    $.fn.fullpage.destroy('all');
                }
            };

            var sanatizeOptions = function (options) {
                options.afterRender = afterAngularRender;
                options.onLeave = onAngularLeave;
                options.onSlideLeave = onAngularSlideLeave;

                function afterAngularRender() {
                    //We want to remove the HREF targets for navigation because they use hashbang
                    //They still work without the hash though, so its all good.
                    if (options && options.navigation) {
                        $('#fp-nav').find('a').removeAttr('href');
                    }

                    if (pageIndex) {
                        $timeout(function () {
                            $.fn.fullpage.silentMoveTo(pageIndex, slideIndex);
                        });
                    }
                }

                function onAngularLeave(page, next, direction) {

                    if (typeof onLeave === 'function' && onLeave(page, next, direction) === false) {
                        return false;
                    }
                    pageIndex = next;

                }

                function onAngularSlideLeave(anchorLink, page, slide, direction, next) {

                    if (typeof onSlideLeave === 'function' && onSlideLeave(anchorLink, page, slide, direction, next) === false) {
                        return false;
                    }
                    pageIndex = page;
                    slideIndex = next;

                }

                //if we are using a ui-router, we need to be able to handle anchor clicks without 'href="#thing"'
                $(document).on('click', '[data-menuanchor]', function () {
                    $.fn.fullpage.moveTo($(this).attr('data-menuanchor'));
                });

                return options;
            };

            var watchNodes = function () {
                return element[0].getElementsByTagName('*').length;
            };

            scope.$watch(watchNodes, rebuild);

            scope.$watch('options', rebuild, true);

            element.on('$destroy', destroyFullPage);
        }
    }

})();
```

Comment: This "collision" is not supposed to happen. Maybe you could show us the code in which you try to use both directives, you might be misusing them when both are present.

Comment: In fact, I'm not using both directives in the HTML. I only need to use one or the other at any given time. However, since I need to inject them both in the app.js, it's the declaration that generates the collision (when I remove 'mgcrea.bootstrap.affix' from the app.js, fullpage Works just fine). Maybe I'm looking at it the wrong way, but since I have no clue of the issue, I'm just focusing on the symptoms.

Answer (score 1):

Does the second depends on the first one? If does, are you compiling the directive one before embedding the second?

If you have 'collision' it's means that you're using some sort of 'use strict', would be more valuable if you show part of the code and see if transclude is part of the directive.

Comment: Nope, they don't depend on each other, When both are injected in app.js, affix works well but fullpage fails.If I remove the affix directive from app.js, then fullpage Works well. I have tried placing affix before fullpage and the other way around, but the problema persists. I have updated the question to include both directives.

Comment: What are you trying to do with this line?

element.on('$destroy', destroyFullPage);